# Value of optional type 'AVCaptureDevice?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'AVCaptureDevice'

Tags: swift

I was following a tutorial on how to capture a barcode scanner from an ipad camera and this is the code that was written. The tutorial was written in xcode 8 and I am using Xcode 10. I am getting an error that

> "Value of optional type 'AVCaptureDevice?' must be unwrapped to a
>   value of type 'AVCaptureDevice'"

in the do try catch statement. Can someone please tell me the correct way to deal with the optional value in this situation? When I change the line to read             "let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)"
the app crashes.

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()    //contains what the camera is pointing at

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //creates session
        let session = AVCaptureSession()

        //define capture device
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

        do{
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)//Error occurs here
            session.addInput(input) //input coming from camera
        }
        catch{
            print("Error")
        }
        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        session.addOutput(output)

        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code93, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39]   //may need to change this based on barcode type
        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(video)
        session.startRunning()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I searched answer for this issue, it first showed your question only. Then I sought help from my colleague as well as finally it run without any error. Try below code.

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

do{
     let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
         if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
              self.captureSession.addInput(input)
         }
}
catch{
        print("Error")
}
```